# Using pnpm, how do I create a package.json for two dependencies of same version (with alias) one with a patch (patchedDependencies) and one without?

Tags: npm, package.json, pnpm

In my package json I currently have:

```json
{
  "name": "examples-valid-misc",
  "dependencies": {
    "jsii-code-samples": "1.7.0",
    "jsii-code-samples-gz": "npm:jsii-code-samples@1.7.0"
  }
}
```

I want the second one to be patched using `patchedDependencies`
How can I achieve this? Anything I do leads to:
`ERR_PNPM_PATCH_NOT_APPLIED  The following patches were not applied: jsii-code-samples-gz`

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be supported.

I have installed the module and its alias:

```bash
pnpm add jsii-code-samples@1.7.0
pnpm add jsii-code-samples-gz@npm:jsii-code-samples
C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>more package.json
{
        "dependencies": {
                "jsii-code-samples": "1.7.0",
                "jsii-code-samples-gz": "npm:jsii-code-samples@^1.7.0"
        }
}
```

I can test it with a testjsii.js:

```js
// Import the HelloWorld class from the jsii-code-samples module
const { HelloWorld } = require('jsii-code-samples');

// Create a new instance of the HelloWorld class
const helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

// Call the sayHello() method on the HelloWorld instance
const greeting = helloWorld.sayHello('Your Name');

// Log the greeting to the console
console.log(greeting);
```

And:

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>node testjsii.js
Hello, Your Name
```

But when I try to patch the alias only:

```bash
pnpm patch jsii-code-samples-gz@1.7.0
 ERR_PNPM_PATCH_VERSION_NOT_FOUND  Can not find jsii-code-samples-gz@1.7.0 in project C:\Users\vonc\node\t1, did you forget to install jsii-code-samples-gz@1.7.0?
```

I can patch the original module:

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>pnpm patch jsii-code-samples
You can now edit the following folder: C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Temp\2ed5f5afcd9f3b0f616c1bf1a3301f6b

Once you're done with your changes, run "pnpm patch-commit C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Temp\2ed5f5afcd9f3b0f616c1bf1a3301f6b"

C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>pnpm patch-commit C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Temp\2ed5f5afcd9f3b0f616c1bf1a3301f6b
Packages: -1
-
Progress: resolved 1, reused 2, downloaded 0, added 1, done

C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>more package.json
{
        "dependencies": {
                "jsii-code-samples": "1.7.0",
                "jsii-code-samples-gz": "npm:jsii-code-samples@^1.7.0"
        },
        "pnpm": {
                "patchedDependencies": {
                        "jsii-code-samples@1.7.0": "patches/jsii-code-samples@1.7.0.patch"
                }
        }
}
```

But, using the modified testjsii.js script:

```js
// require the jsii-code-samples package
const HelloWorld = require('jsii-code-samples').HelloWorld;
const helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

// require the jsii-code-samples package installed under the alias jsii-code-samples-gz
const HelloWorldGz = require('jsii-code-samples-gz').HelloWorld;
const helloWorldGz = new HelloWorldGz();

console.log(helloWorld.sayHello('Your Name'));
console.log(helloWorldGz.sayHello('Your Name'));
```

You would see that both return the same patched output:

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\node\t1>node testjsii.js
Hello PATCHED2, Your Name
Hello PATCHED2, Your Name
```

Even though `patchedDependencies` only reference one of the two.

---

To achieve what you want, you might not be able to use an alias, but a fork of your module, published on npm, and installed separately.